# $scope not working, content not populating

Tags: angularjs-scope, ngroute

I've been looking at this for days and can not figure out why my content isn't populating the mustaches on my page! The only error message I'm getting is that $scope is not defined, but I'm not sure where the problem is. Any help would be much appreciated-- thanks!

itemlistcontroller.js file:

```
vegApp.controller('itemListController', function ($scope){
$scope.items = [
        {imageurl: 'images/strawb.jpg', type: 'strawberry', name: 'Herbert     Strawberry', occupation: 'dogwalker', superpower: 'power-C boost'},
        {imageurl: 'images/blueb.jpg', type: 'blueberry', name: 'Ulysses  Blueberry', occupation: 'construction worker', superpower: 'super strength' },
        {imageurl: 'images/orange.jpg' , type: 'orange', name: 'Otto Sly Orange', occupation: 'ninja', superpower: 'serious defense' }
    ]});
    $scope.new_item = {};
$scope.add_item_error = "";

$scope.additem = function(item){
        $scope.items.push( item );
        $scope.adding_item = {};
    };

    console.log('scope', $scope);
]);
```

app.js file:

```
var vegApp = angular.module('vegApp', []);

vegApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'index3.html',
        controller: 'itemListController'
    })
    .when('/login', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
        controller: 'registration'
    })
    .when('/moreinfo', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/moreinfo.html',
        controller: 'moreinfo'
    })
    .when('/recipes', {
        templateUrl: 'recipes.html',
        controller: 'recipes'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/login'
    });
}
]);
```

HTML file:

```
<html ngApp="vegApp">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" text="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular/js/angular.js"></script>
<script src="text/javascript" src="angular/js/angular-route.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```
</head>
<body ng-controller='itemListController'>

<ng-view>


<div class="main">
  <h2>Summon your Vitamin Power</h2>
  <form name="add_item_form" novalidate ng-submit="additem()">
    <input type="text" placeholder="what'd you eat?" ng-model="searchFor" ng-required="true"/>

    <button ng-click="additem()" ng-disabled="add_item_form.$invalid" class="btn btn-success">Add to Your Arsenal</button>

    <ul class = "itemgroup" ng-repeat= "item in items | filter:searchFor">
      <div class="adding_item">
        <li ng-model="items.imageurl">
          <img ng-src ="{{ item.imageurl }}" alt="{{ item.type }}">
        </li>
        <li ng-model="items.type">
          {{ item.type }}
        </li>
        <li ng-model="items.name">
          {{ item.name }}
        </li>
        <li ng-model="items.occupation" >
          {{ item.occupation }}
        </li>
        <li ng-model="items.superpower">
          {{ item.superpower }}
        </li>
      </div>
    </ul>

  </form>

</div>

</div>
</ng-view>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would probably help if you would include the error message, more than just "$scope is not defined".

Comment: `ng-app="vegApp"` not `ngApp="vegApp"`

Answer (score 0):

Updated:

It seems that in your HTML, you set the ng-model's of your list items to 'items.'. This doesn't make sense, since there is, for example, no property 'type' in $scope.items; it is an array. Instead, since 'item' is already a reference to an item in the scope, you can simply write ng-model="item." in your HTML.

Your itemListController looks a bit malformed. Your function ends right after you defined $scope.items, so $scope isn't in the scope of where you are console-logging $scope. Try replacing your itemlistcontroller.js with this:

```
vegApp.controller('itemListController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        {
            imageurl: 'images/strawb.jpg',
            type: 'strawberry',
            name: 'Herbert     Strawberry',
            occupation: 'dogwalker',
            superpower: 'power-C boost'
        },
        {
            imageurl: 'images/blueb.jpg',
            type: 'blueberry',
            name: 'Ulysses  Blueberry',
            occupation: 'construction worker',
            superpower: 'super strength'
        },
        {
            imageurl: 'images/orange.jpg',
            type: 'orange',
            name: 'Otto Sly Orange',
            occupation: 'ninja',
            superpower: 'serious defense'
        }
    ];
    $scope.new_item = {};
    $scope.add_item_error = "";

    $scope.additem = function (item) {
        $scope.items.push(item);
        $scope.adding_item = {};
    };

    console.log('scope', $scope);
});
```

Comment: thanks-- content still isn't populating the mustaches, though. Although now there are no error messages....

Comment: Hey, I updated the answer. It appears that your ng-models are pointing to the wrong thing.

Comment: Thanks! So instead of <li ng-model="item.type"> or <li ng-model="item.name">? I can just say <li ng-model="item"> for all of them? I tried that and it still didn't work.

Comment: No, you would write <li ng-model="item.type"> and <li ng-model="item.name">. In your markup, however, you wrote <li ng-model="items.type"> and <li ng-model="items.name">. Notice the 's' after 'item.'

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, and what I get on the page is still {{item.type}} {{item.name}}, etc..